# PHP If statement

Tags: php, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use X pages of PDF using FPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643889/how-to-use-x-pages-of-pdf-using-fpdf)

I  have a long text that is stored in $text.

My $text contains about 10 lines of string seperated with "\n".

I have to seperate this text into x of pages in PDF by using this code.

```
$textArray = explode("\n",$text);

$pdf1 = implode("\n", array_slice($textArray, 0, 2));

$pdf2 = implode("\n", array_slice($textArray, 2, 2));

$pdf3 = implode("\n", array_slice($textArray, 4, 2));

$pdf4 = implode("\n", array_slice($textArray, 6, 2));

$pdf5 = implode("\n", array_slice($textArray, 8));
```

If all $pdf are filled in with strings (up to $pdf5), I want to store this value for:

```
$pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\5pg.pdf";
```

BUT if the text/string only stored up $pdf4, and $pdf5 should be NULL or blank, I want to store this value for:

```
$pdf_original = "forms\pdfForms\4pg.pdf";
```

The list goes on until ONLY if I use $pdf1, then I want $pdf_original to be "forms\pdfForms\1pg.pdf";

Basically:

```
1pg.pdf = 1 page PDF = text will be stored up to $pdf1. $pdf2-5 will be NULL/Blank

2pg.pdf = 2 page PDF = text will be stored up to $pdf2. $pdf3-5 will be NULL/Blank

3pg.pdf = 3 page PDF = text will be stored up to $pdf3. $pdf4-5 will be NULL/Blank

4pg.pdf = 4 page PDF = text will be stored up to $pdf4. $pdf5 will be NULL/Blank

5pg.pdf = 5 page PDF = text will be stored up to $pdf5.
```

Comment: Possible double post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643889/how-to-use-x-pages-of-pdf-using-fpdf

Answer (score 3):

I think you are better off using a multidimensional array. This would distribute the lines evenly over the number of provided pages:

```
$pages = 5;
$textArray = explode("\n", $text);
$linesPerPage = ceil(count($textArray)/$pages);

$pages = array_chunk($textArray, $linesPerPage);
foreach($pages as $k => $page) {
    $pages[$k] = implode("\n", $page);
}

$pdf_original = sprintf("forms\pdfForms\%dpg.pdf", count($pages));
```

Comment: @yes123: :D I started writing something with `implode` but decided to to do it in a loop ;) Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the reply, Felix King. However, when I have 1 line of text it prints 2pg.pdf instead of 1pg.pdf. If I have 2 lines of text, it prints 3pg.pdf instead of 1pg.pdf. If I have 3 lines of text, it prints 5pg.pdf instead of 2pg.pdf. If I have 4 lines of text, it prints 3pg.pdf instead of 2pg.pdf.

Comment: @Arnold: Maybe you have an empty line at the end. And as I said, it tries to evenly distribute the number of lines on the pages.